# How to properly impute values on the test set using imputer (missForest)

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, data-imputation, train-test-split

I'm trying to impute some missing values on my dataset $X$. So first I shuffle and split data to obatin the train set `X_train` and the test set `X_test`.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify = y, shuffle = True, test_size = 0.25)
```

Then I am imputing values using *missForest* algorithm, but only in the train set

```
imputer = MissForest(max_iter = 10, verbose = 0)
X_train_imp = imputer.fit_transform(X_train)
```

**Now, what's the proper way of imputing the test set?**

1. Use `transform()` function as follows

```
X_test_imp = imputer.transform(X_test)
```

**OR**

2. Combine **imputed** train set and test set and only then impute values in the test set

```
X_combined = pd.concat([X_train_imp, Xtest])
imputer_conc = MissForest(max_iter = 10, verbose = 0)
X_conc_imp = imputer_conc.fit_transform(X_combined)
X_conc_imp = pd.DataFrame(Xconc_imp)

Xtrain_imp = Xconc_imp.loc[:X_train_imp.shape[0] - 1]
Xtest_imp = Xconc_imp.loc[X_train_imp.shape[0]:]
```

The first approach seems to allow no data leakage, however the second one takes advantage of the avaliable test set (I simply have it) - but I'm curious to what degree it could cause data leakage.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `imputer.transform(test)` to get accurate generalization metrics from your model. If you use the whole dataset, then you will *leak* information to training data from the test. e.g. - assume you are using mean to impute your data - if take the mean of the whole dataset and then use this value to impute, then you are leaking information from test to train as your mean is derived from test data as well.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but the thing is, that for `missForest` such approach is impossible, as it retrains on the test data.